# Wordpress horizontal scrolling bug

Tags: css, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling

I bought this theme, i customized it, edited some code and now apparently i can scroll a lot horizontally. I already opened a ticket to the theme's owner but it's probably going to take more than 24 hours and i do not have those 24 hours.

[This is the website.](http://superspeed.ro) Try scrolling to right.

I tried adding width: 100% to different divs but without succes.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry you purchased broken code, but when you come here to post a question, please be prepared to follow the guidelines. Do not just post a link, because once you fix your problem, this question becomes useless to future readers.  Post the relevant code in the question.  Please see http://sscce.org

Comment: These kinds of issues can be easily tracked down once you learn how to use the DOM inspection tools built into your browser.

Comment: Hello @Sparky. I'm sorry for the way i posted the question. I was kind of under the clock. Beside, i could not know what line of CSS to paste in here, and pasting the entire CSS would have been way too much. I'm looking over sscce.org right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your **superspeed.ro #3** .css file, *line 71* (***#content-wrap***). Disable (add /* `padding: 0 40px 40px;` */ ) or line.

content-wrap{padding: 0 40px 40px;}

1. Open your **layout.css?ver=1.72** .css file, *line 10* (***.container***). Disable (add /* `width: 960px;` */ ) or delete line.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, i applied what you said and it has solved the initial bug, but caused a minor secundary bug. The content from every page is in .container. By removing his width of 960 pixels, the margin: 0 auto; cannot align the content to center anymore. I tried adding width: 100% but did not worked. Any solution of how to center the content?
Thanks

Comment: Never mind, i fixed it :)

Here's what fixed it:
#content-wrap .container, #teaser .container
{
 width: 960px;
}

I'll mark this as the right answer!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not an bug from WordPress, its an error by your Stylesheet/CSS.

```
 #content-wrap {
      padding: 0px 40px 40px 40px;
 }
```

If you remove this, you can see, the Horizontal scrolling will be disbaled. Your **#content-wrap** has **more width** than **html/body**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements causing it:

`.nav_wrap` has a `margin-left` of `840px` -- that's causing some.

The other is caused by the `40px` padding on `#content-wrap`